# Reading from set of files

Tags: c++, file

I am a newbie so please don't be harsh on me for asking simple questions. my main question is how can I read from several files located in a directory sequently using a loop in c++ and perform some actions on them? 
My code is like this:

```
string corpus = "corpus.txt";

myfile.open(corpus);
if (myfile.is_open())
    while (!myfile.eof()) 
    {
        //Do something

    }//end of while


    MergeFiles(corpus,count);`
```

How can I do this actions on a set of files instead of just one.

Comment: Can you get a list of the files? What OS are you using?

Comment: Are you wanting to get a list of all files in a specific directory? If so you might want to update your question to clarify that.

Comment: Windows, I don't know how I can to do this task

Comment: @OldAzhdar what task? getting all file names from a directory or iterating?

Comment: I just wanna do what I do now for a single file, for a set of text files instead of just one , suppose they're located on "D:\new\\*.txt"

Comment: I don't know. I think if i could have list of files it could help through what i wanna do . so how can i get that list?

Comment: @OldAzhdar you can hard code it (DON'T!), use windows API or a third party code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could do one of the following:

- use windows APIs
- use third party code

It looks like the simplest way is using [diren.h](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php). Look for at the sample code here:
[How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

you can use the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/), more specific - [the filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator). This is more powerful but complicated solution, requires you to use iterators and higher programming methods.

using the windows API is not recommended because it requires dipper understanding of windows, and won't result a portable code. If you want to use it, there is an example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I was editing it, slipped on the key board, and published. Just edited.

Comment: I recommend sitting on a chair rather than standing on your keyboard.